# .bashrc/.bash_profile not loading export

Tags: macos, bash, bashrc, .bash-profile

I'm trying to compile code and in order to get it to work I need to run the following line before compilation:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

After this the code compiles normally, I'm trying to add this so that I do not need to run this line each time when I restart my PC. I've tried adding that line to the `.bashrc` file (does the file path needs quotes?) which has not seemed to work. I have also tried creating a `.bash_profile` file an adding the line in there but again this does not seem to work.

Whenever I try to compile after adding the `.bash_profile` I am getting the following error:

`./makeScript: line 1: pkg-config: command not found`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

Comment: What's then first line of: `makeScript`?

Comment: `g++ -std=c++11 $1 -o $2 \`pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv\` ` I have tried removing the hyphen is that line as well to no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work if you added it into `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`.

If this won't work, make sure your script actually uses `bash` shell ([shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))), as if you're using different shell, possibly it won't be loaded.

However I think your problem is not related to `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, but `PATH` variable which doesn't contain the right directory where `pkg-config` executable binary is present.

Check by:

```
$ which pkg-config
/usr/local/bin/pkg-config
```

If you can't find it, make sure you've installed it and linked it, e.g. using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

```
brew install pkg-config; brew link pkg-config
```

And your `/usr/local/bin` is in your `PATH`, e.g.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

---

As a side note, you can check your export variables by running `set` command just before the link which fails.

Another thing to track the problem is to debug your scripts by running like: `bash -x ./makeScript` or adding `-x` at the end of your [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) (e.g. `#!/bin/bash -x`).

Answer (score 0):

Take `~/.profile`:

```
$ cat >> ~/.profile << EOF
> PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
> EOF
```

Load changes (if you do not want to reboot):

```
$ source ~/.profile
```

Test:

```
$ echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

Comment: That resulted in the error `pkg-config: command not found` when I tried to compile.

Comment: Maybe typing mistakes? You have once hyphens and once none

Comment: `echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH` results in `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`, does that look correct?

Comment: Yes when its the normal command for your configuration. if pkgconfig doesn't exist at all, the answer is useless. In oyur script you seem to call `pkg-config` although your variable navigates to `pkgconfig` ; missing hyphen

Comment: I added in the hyphen and got the error `pkg-config: command not found`. `echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH` `/usr/local/lib/pkg-config`.